# How to implement thread-safe map of maps in golang?

Tags: multithreading, go, hashmap, thread-safety, goroutine

I am working on a multi-threaded module and need to implement map of map in golang - `map[outer]map[inner]*some_struct`. The outer key(map[outer]) will be accessed by multiple threads(goroutines) to add key to inner map. I have a doubt if multiple threads can concurrently add keys to inner map, for a common outer key - map[outer]. Is it thread safe and is sync.Map a better option ?
Also outer key- map[outer] and total number of outer keys are known at runtime so can't define locks beforehand.

To better understand the problem statement, we can take example of add information about different cities. We can group cities by states. Each thread represents a city. To add info about a city, first thread needs to check outer key - state,(map[state]) and then each thread will simply add info to `map[state][city] = &some_struct{x:y,y:z}`.

I have read few articles and found out sync.Map is suitable for concurrent map operations and these operations are performed atomically. But in documentation one of the use-case mentioned was - **when multiple goroutines read, write, and overwrite entries for *disjoint sets of keys***.

It will be helpful if someone can suggest thread-safe approach for this problem statement.

Comment: One lock for the outer map, one lock for each inner map.

Comment: `I have a doubt if multiple threads can concurrently add keys to inner map`. no it is not thread safe. `is sync.Map a better option ?` It depends. Often there is more to do than a read/write within a tx. Further more, the way sync.Map is implemented often gives a false sense of security to someone unexperienced.

Comment: @mh-cbon can you elaborate your last remark about false sense of security?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/5V91pybxm-p

Answer (score -3):

You must thing in OO terms

What do you want to represent as map of map?

Map state, city make some sense. However what kind of operations do you want to do?

Write and Read, concurrent? Why?

Do you want to iterate over all cities? Do you need to delete cities/states?

Imagine the following interface

```golang
type DB interface {
  Exists(state, city string) bool
  Get(state, city string) *some_struct
  Set(state, city string, data *some_struct)
  Delete(state, city string)
  DeleteState(state string)
  ForeachCitiesInState(state string, func(city string, data *some_struct) bool)
  Foreach(func(state, city…))
}
```

With this interface we can consider:

1. use a struct with a Mutex and map of maps to control the access on each read/write/delete
2. same as 1 but with Read Write Mutex if you have more reads than writes
3. if you don’t need loop over cities on a particular state, perhaps
   you can create a map[ composite key ] struct like `state:city` to
   simplify.
4. If you will load it from another place with a constant time interval, perhaps you should use atomic.Value to store the big map. Update is just a substitution for a more recent map.
5. Perhaps you can combine several rw locks. For instance one for state and another for city. You can split like

```golang
type states struct {
sync.Mutex
map[ stateName ]state
}

type state struct {
sync.Mutex
map[ cityFirstLetter ]cities
}

type cities struct {
sync.Mutex
map[ cityName ] *some_struct
}
```

Ideas:

1. Define the interface
2. Define (or measure) the real scenario of usage
3. Write benchmarks
4. Be careful by return a pointer to data. You can change the internal state. Consider return a copy or an interface